# detect irrational mouse movement in windows and initiate support

Tags: mouse, mousemove, onmousemove

I dont know if you could implement sth. like this but maybe you guys know an answer. I have to come up with a programm for Windows which runs at all times and detects irrational mouse movement left to right and back in a quick manner. If said movement is detected a popoup should appear asking the current user if there is a Problem and if she needs Support. When she does an automatic redirect should bring her to the support portal.

Would a gesture Programm for Windows solve my Problem?

thanks for your help!

Comment: You need to provide more information about what language or platform you have created your program with. It might be that the platform or language you are using have already built some mouse gesture library of some kind that can be reused.

Comment: I use a normal Windows 10 Laptop. As far as Program languages are concerned im open minded.

Comment: The tricky part here is to get the mouse movement detection right. Can you define what makes an irrational mouse movement? Let's say the algorithm looks for 1px to the left and then 1px to the right - it would trigger every time a person moves the mouse to the right. Maybe you would consider defining trigger positions in stead of movements, like if the mouse cursor is in a particular corner of the screen. Probably easier to implement too.